# Azure SQL Data Sync between SQL Azure and Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, synchronization, maintenance

I used two have 2 SQL Azure databases and they were automatically synced using this service: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/

Now one of the databases had been moved to an Azure Virtual Machine.

How can I sync them now? Azure SQL Data Sync seems to only allow to choose SQL Azure database.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: I had to install *SQL Data Sync Client Agent* on the server, then it will show up in Azure Management:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823137.aspx